# Django app - Virtualenv upgrading my package with my project

Tags: python, django, package, virtualenv, pip

Here is the context:
I have a project with an app that I just packaged following the [standard packaging tutorial for django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/reusable-apps/)

```shell
my-app $ python setup.py sdist
```

I've installed my app into my project

```shell
(myenv)myproject $ pip install path/to/my-app/packaged
```

Now when I need to modify my app, I do the modifications, then

```shell
my-app $ python setup.py sdist
(myenv)myproject $ pip uninstall my-app
(myenv)myproject $ pip install path/to/my-app/packaged
```

Shouldn't there be an easier manner to accomplish this ?

---

**Update**

My idea is to upgrade both my project and my app, so I'll have a lot of commits going through.
Then when I think my app is versionable I'd package it. (Not sure I had been clear)

Comment: If you change version of the package you can use `pip install --upgrade` and omit `pip uninstall`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to edit your app and actually see the changes in your project without reinstalling/upgrading your app each time something changed, you could install your app in **[editable](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/logic.html#editable-installs)** mode:

```
pip install -e path/to/yourproject
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to me the best way (I didn't know about the _editable mode_). I've not been able to use it (I know nothing about _setuptools_) but this is another issue.

Comment: Ok I think I understand why I wasn't able to make it work. I didn't get that I still had to upgrade the package in my project after each modification.

Comment: ... no, you shouldn't have to upgrade the package manually. Installed with ```pip install -e``` your app should be symlinked in your site-packages and therefore all changes should be immediately reflected in your app.

Comment: Ok then I'll make a new SO question. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pip install --upgrade <path>`

Have you considered it?

Comment: It sounds to me that you need some sort of a bash script to help you with packing and unpacking your app. Or a git hook if you are using git.